# Can icomplete mode be enabled selectively, only for certain commands?

Tags: completion, minibuffer, icomplete

I'd like to use icomplete-mode for certain commands, but not for everything. Is there a way to enable it for just a list of commands I specify?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Currently, the only way icomplete offers to control it is via `icomplete-with-completion-tables` which is rather inflexible.  Of course, you could enable/disable it for specific commands by advising those commands and temporarily rebinding `icomplete-with-completion-tables` accordingly.

Comment: I tried simple around advising, turning icomplete on and off, but it doesn't work for some reason `(defun my-icomplete (orig-fun &rest args)
  (icomplete-mode 1)
  (apply orig-fun args)
  (icomplete-mode -1))


(advice-add 'describe-variable :around 'my-icomplete)`

Comment: @Tom: This advice applies to the execution of the *function*, i.e. the code run once we know which arguments to pass to the function, whereas you need the advice to apply to the *construction* of those arguments, i.e. the interactive spec.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I tried advising completing-read, but apparently I can't detect the current command while the arguments are gathered. Shouldn't this-command show this? Even if the command is not executing yet, its arguments are being gathered, so this-command could indicate the current command already.